# Python boolean comparison: False == not(True) SyntaxError

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, boolean, ipython

The following expression is evaluated to `True`

```
In [1]: not(True) == False
Out[2]: True
```

However, changing the order of evaluation returns a strange result!

```
In [3]: False == not(True)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    (False == not(True))
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any reason you’re not just using != ?

Comment: If you are using ```not``` right after ```==``` sign, you need to wrap it with a parathesis like this:   
```
True == (not(False))
```

Comment: @Sayse Yes, this is just the final evaluation of a more complex expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the below code:

```
>>> False == (not True)
True
>>>
```

Because the code runs from left to right, so it would first run `False == not` which is a `SyntaxError`.

```
>>> False == not
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: Merci for the answer; parentheses always do the magic!

Comment: @sci9 Haha yeah